# Images.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Axios.get is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

**I am getting the following error in React.**

Images.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Axios.get is not a function

I followed the following process.

1. I install the npm install axios.
   2)then I try to use the method get()
   for that, I imported the axios> import { Axios } from 'axios';

Here is my function

```
           inputRef.current.focus()
           Axios.get("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=Q6F2UZogduuqcTc6rRGUs6ZOIo8yhNIpP4tiJHm0CrE").then(res => {
               console.log(res);
           } ).then(res => {
               console.log(res);
           });
          // console.log(varRef);
    
    },[]);
```

after that I run npm run start and got blank but in console, I am getting the
Images.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Axios.get is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried renaming the import to as followed:

`import axios from "axios";`

this is what worked for me

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason? but it is working

Comment: I think it's due to how `default exports` (`export default Name`) compared to `named exports` (`export const Name`). This link should be able to give more info than I can https://techtalkbook.com/use-of-curly-braces-in-es6-import/

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
```

Not the used below, since `axios` is exporting it as the "default"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

```
import { Axios } from 'axios';
```

Answer (score 0):

With webpack module federation, capitalizing the A in the `shared` config was all that was necessary:

```js
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      ...
      shared: {
        Axios: {
          eager: true,
          singleton: true,
        },
      },
    }),
```

[image]